# Differential form of "random walk with reset" based on Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Assume such a "random walk with reset" X(t) is defined based on Wiener process (GBM)

```
X(t + dt) =  
   0, by probability lambda * dt; or, 
   X(t) + dW, by probability (1 - lambda * dt)
```

, where lambda is a constant, and

```
dW = W(t+dt) - W(t),
```

while W is a Wiener process (GBM).

What is the differential form for X? 
I'd like to have something like

```
dX = ( 1 - lambda * dt) * dW + lambda * dt * ....
```

so that I could use this with Ito's lemma to do some calculus.

Comment: The random walk that is in your mind must have jump discontinuities, which is not allowed in Ito process. So it should be a Levy process. I know not much about this subject, though...

Comment: @sos440 , thanks for the comments, however for such X, dX is dependent on X(t), so it's not i.i.d. Then it's even not a "random process", other than Levy.... I'm a bit lost here...

Comment: What is GBM?  I assume BM is Brownian Motion, but what is the G?

Comment: @Nate: GBM is usually a geometric Brownian motion:
$$
dX_t = \mu X_tdt+\sigma X_t dW_t.
$$
Though it's not a Wiener process, so I'm a bit confused about OP.

Comment: @Athos: Let me consider the case when $W_t = B_t$ is just a Brownian motion and $N_t$ is a Poisson process with an intensity $\lambda$, then the process
$$
\mathrm dX_t = -X_t\cdot \mathrm dN_t + \mathrm dB_t
$$
should satisfy your conditions. Informally speaking, when the Poisson process does not have a jump in $[t,t+dt)$ (which is of probability $1-\lambda \cdot\mathrm dt$) then $X_t$ evolves like a Brownian motion, while at a moment of jump - it jumps to the $0$ since 
$$
-X_t\cdot \mathrm dN_t = -X_t \cdot \Delta N_t
$$
where $\Delta N_t = N_t - N_{t-}$

Comment: ...though I am not completely sure, so I will take a look into literature on Monday.

Comment: geometric Brownian motion http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion

Comment: @athos: geometric Brownian motion *is not* a Wiener process, please fix it in OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let me expand my comment into an answer. Let $W_t$ be either a geometric Brownian motion, or a Brownian motion, or any Ito process - it does not matter for our case, we only will use the continuity properties of the process.

The idea is to use the [Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process) in order to describe jumps, namely let $N_t$ be the Poisson process with a given intensity $\lambda$, so the probability of jump for $N_t$ in the interval $[t,t+dt]$ is roughly $\lambda\cdot dt$.

The question now is: the jumps of a Poisson process is always equal to $1$ whenever it happens, so how to use it for your problem? The good thing about a Poisson process it that it has piecewise-constant paths, which are of finite variatino with probability one so the integral is easy to define: for any function $f:\mathbb R_{+}\to\mathbb R$ which has limits from the left
$$
\int\limits_0^t f(t)dN_t = \sum\limits_{s\leq t}f(s-)\Delta N_s \tag{1}
$$
where $f(s -) = \lim\limits_{r\uparrow s}f(r)$ and $\Delta N_s = N_s - N_{s-}$. Note that a Poisson process has finitely many jumps in each interval $[0,t]$ with probability $1$, so the summation in $(1)$ is finite.

If we manage to make $X_t$ jump to zero at each moment $N_t$ has a jump, we solve the problem. How should we derive an equation, though? Well, suppose that $N_t$ has jumps at times 
$$
t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n<\dots
$$
and consider $t\in [t_{i},t_{i+1})$ - there the process $X_t$ behaves as $W_t$ since there are no jumps:
$$
X_t = (X_{t_i}-W_{t_i})+W_t\quad\text{ for }t\in[t_i,t_{i+1}).\tag{2}
$$

If we consider a jump at time $t_{i+1}$ downwards, of the absolute value $X_{t_{i+1}}$ it will make everything work. On the other hand, whenever you work with integrals w.r.t. the Poisson process you have to consider limits from the left as in $(1)$. In our case it is ok, since any of processes $W_t$ we considered above has continuous paths and so $W_{t_{i+1}-} = W_{t_i}$. 
Clearly, $-X_{t-}\cdot\Delta N_t$ is what we need since it makes jumps only together $N_t$ makes them and these jumps are of an appropriate value and direction.

As a result, the process defined by
$$
dX_t = - X_{t-}dN_t + dW_t \tag{3}
$$
solves your problem. The explicit formula for such process is given in $(2)$.

For the stochastic calculus of such process, a very nice reference is ["Stochastic Calculus for Finance II" by S. Shreve, Chapter 11.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387401016)

Comment: is the X defined in (3) a semi-martingale?

Comment: @athos: would you first fix OP as requested?